# How to interpolate a variable in a twig loop to render a file?

Tags: wordpress, twig

I am looping through a list of social profiles to render the logo. Each social item has a field of svg_icon_code that looks like "twitter" or "facebook". I want to use this code to render the correct file. Currently I am just hardcoding in "twitter" resulting in all logos being the Twitter svg. How can I use the icon_code to render the correct svg?

```
{% for item in options.social_media_links %}
  <li class="header__social-media-links__item">
     <a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
        {% include 'component/svg-twitter-icon.twig' %}
     </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat the icon like this,

```
{% for item in options.social_media_links %}
  <li class="header__social-media-links__item">
     <a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
        {% include 'component/svg-'~item.svg_icon_code~'-icon.twig' %}
     </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

If an icon doesn't have a template or the template is missing you can do this to render a default icon

```
{% for item in options.social_media_links %}
  <li class="header__social-media-links__item">
     <a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
        {% include [ 'component/svg-'~item.svg_icon_code~'-icon.twig', 'component/svg-default-icon.twig' ]  %}
     </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you